# Modifying Time attribute using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, time

I need to remove the DD-MM-YY from the "Time" attribute and only keep the HH:MM:SS using the modelbuilder. The model is displayed below and I use ArcMap 10.2.

I have tried the "Calculate Field" and the "Right function" but it only works on string.

Is this possible?

[image: I have DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS and only need HH:MM:SS.]

[image: Modelbuilder model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Have` field is of type `date` and your `Needed` field type is of `string`, you can do it with the following statement in the field calculator of Arcmap:

```
!DateFieldName!.split( )[1]
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried .replace(X,Y) code in python?
-replace one with another in the string